# Emgu.CV , CvBlob.BoundingBox throw System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, opencv, access-violation, emgucv

Im using Emgu.CV (OpenCV), to find delta in image, but sometimes I get Access violation exception that cause my app to crash.

After digging in the debug I find that (`blobs.Values`):

```
List<CvBlob> listOfBlobs = blobs.Values.ToList();
```

return 1733 items, and when I do the following:

But when run through the list I get EXCEPTION:

```
 if (resultedRectangles[j].Contains(listOfBlobs[i].BoundingBox))
```

I check and find the exception occurred at: **i = 418** :

> +BoundingBox  '(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(listOfBlobs)).Items[418].BoundingBox'
>   threw an exception of type
>   'System.AccessViolationException' System.Drawing.Rectangle
>   {System.AccessViolationException}

As I see the last valid value in the list is in 417.

I have 2 questions:
1. Why `blobs.Values.ToList();` return such corrupt data?
2. How I can check the value before access it to prevent `System.AccessViolationException` ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you having multiple threads in your Process? If there are multiple threads trying to initialize the List, then the list may get corrupted.

This exception is more specific to Memory related issues and you will be in a hard time to debug this, unless the all the code is in your control. The following link may help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Me too got trapped in the same error.

Comment: Yes I have multi threads, and the function is static (is there any issue with defining the function static when it have not use any static variables (all local to the function), and the image sent to this function (function call) from few diff threads, each thread have its own image instance)

Comment: If the function is static and not accessing any instance variables, then this is thread safe. There will be problems if the initialization of the blobs.Values list is done via multiple threads. While debugging you can check whether the blobs.Values contains no empty values. Also please verify whether the library you are using is free from memory related issues.